# Exit when logging in to Cisco Packet Tracer

Tags: authentication

When I log in the Cisco Packet Tracer authentication page, as long as I click next, the program will automatically exit. If you start the program from the command line, it displays:
Starting Packet Tracer 7.2.2
/usr/local/bin/packettracer: line 8:  6290 Floating point exception(core dumped) ./PacketTracer7 "$@" > /dev/null 2>&1

After debugging with GDB, you will see:
Thread 1 "PacketTracer7" received signal SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception.
0x00007fffeede5ef4 in QFontEngineFT::averageCharWidth() const () from ./libQt5XcbQpa.so.5

Comment: Can you share the full output of gdb?

`cd /opt/pt/bin`

`gdb ./PacketTracer7`

then type

`run`

Answer (score 0):

I received a similar error and spent a lot of time troubleshooting, trying different qt5 library versions and installing a new libpng12 and such. Never got it to work. Then I found Cisco has released version 7.3.0 and it works fine.

FYI here is the exact error I received (in my dmesg) upon clicking the 'Next' button as you described:

```
[Sat Dec 21 21:18:22 2019] traps: PacketTracer7[12228] trap divide error ip:7f8ab1531ef4 sp:7ffd9d9710d0 error:0 in libQt5XcbQpa.so.5[7f8ab1475000+111000]
```